# What causes this jank in Animation Frame Fired and Composite Layer?

Tags: javascript, animation, rendering, requestanimationframe

I'm working on a game and 60fps is ideal.

I've noticed some stuttering and I did a timeline recording of 60 seconds.

I've noticed these two things that were marked as "jank" by the dev tools:

### 1 - Animation Frame Fired

[image: Animation Frame Fired Jank]

You should be able to see that the frame before and after are relatively good (21.3 is slow but nothing like this 80.7) and the graph above shows that practically 99% of frames run well.

From what I can dig into the call stack, this is the code that is being fired here -
[image: code fired]

It's part of the framework I'm using (Famous.org), so it looks like it just steps through the looper and calls "rAF" which I've shown in the console is requestAnimationFrame().

What could be causing this call to slow down so much? Is it something to do with the browser rather than my code?

### 2 - Composite Layers

Pretty much same thing here except that Composite Layers doesn't reference any code in the call stack (the second image is the other janky frame in the Timeline) - 
[image: composite layer jank 1]
[image: composite layer jank 2]

Where are these performance drops coming from?

Comment: Did you find any answers?

Comment: @bartzy not really, it's possible it was choke due to other processes but no way to confirm